# jQuery attribute selector in IE9

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes

This returns undefined in IE9 but works fine in all other modern browsers.

```
var new_src = $("img[alt=\"" + value + "\"]").attr('src');
```

How can I make it work for all IEs?

Thank you!

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle to replicate this issue?

Comment: seems to work fine here in IE9 http://jsfiddle.net/V76NB/

Comment: I see nothing wrong either.. not sure why you are using the escape character stuff but looks fine to me. JQuery is cross-browser compatible so you shouldn't have any issue. Perhaps another part of your code is conflicting with it? Can you show us more relevant code?

Comment: I have a lot of special characters for the "value". I think that may be the reason why.. I'm going to make everything lowercase, replace characters, etc, and see if that works. Thanks all for your help!